# Debug Multiple Apps at once in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

Is it possible to debug multiple applications, on one machine, in Delphi XE2 at the same time?  I have two (actually, three, but the middle one works fine) that send messages to each other.  I would like to be able to debug both programs at the same time.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run all projects in a project group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154343/how-do-i-run-all-projects-in-a-project-group)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Make sure all of the projects you want to debug in your project group have been compiled.  Then right click and select "Run" on each project you want to debug.

I just tried this in XE2 with two very simple VCL applications and it works as expected, including breakpoints in both projects.