# How do I have a Delphi Application contain multiple processes?

Tags: delphi

I've noticed that the Threads Window in the Delphi IDE seems to support multiple processes (not just threads).  And now I have to wonder how one creates additional processes beyond the application itself so that they appear in the Threads Window?

What code would I have to write to create a multi-processes application, not just a multi-thread one?

Assuming it's possible.

Comment: If you want to create a new process, you can use `CreateProcess`. (But it is not exactly clear what you mean by "a Delphi Application contain[ing] multiple processes".)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand so that the process appears in the Threads Window as a process in the Delphi IDE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debug Multiple Apps at once in Delphi XE2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830213/debug-multiple-apps-at-once-in-delphi-xe2)

Comment: @SilverWarior This puts each process in the threads window, so I guess it does.  I had thought might be related to an application containing multiple processes, rather than multiple applications.

Comment: Define application please